# Google Cloud Function terminated with "response error" intermittently when using Node.js - Express Framework and returning small amounts of data

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function built with Node.js and the Express framework that is triggered by a Cloud Pub/Sub topic. The function reads messages from the topic and performs some processing before sending a response. However, sometimes the function is terminated with the error message "response error". This happens intermittently, and I'm having trouble identifying the root cause of the issue.

It's worth noting that my function doesn't return a lot of data. It simply returns a small JSON object back to the Pub/Sub topic. Additionally, the function has been configured with sufficient resources, so I don't believe that resource constraints are the issue.

This is my code:

```
import * as express from 'express';
export function initializeExpress(app = express()): void {
  app.put(`${endpoint}`, (req, res) => {
    service
      .process(req, res, new RequestHandler())
      .then()
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  });
}

.
.
.

export class Service {
  public async process(request: Request, response: Response, requestHandler: RequestHandler): Promise<void> {
    const processResponse: ProcessResponse = await requestHandler.processRequest(request);

    response.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
    response.status(200).send(processResponse);
  }
}

.
.
.

export class RequestHandler {
  processRequest(request: Request): ProcessResponse | ErrorResponse {
    return {
      title: 'Created',
      status: 201,
    } as ProcessResponse;
  }
}
```

Here's what I have already tried:

- Checked the logs for any errors or exceptions, but didn't find anything relevant.
- Increased the timeout value of the cloud function, but the issue still persists.
- Checked the Pub/Sub topic for any issues, but everything seems to be working fine.

The only error message that appears in the logs is "Function execution took 2530 ms, finished with status: 'response error'".
I'm wondering if the issue is related to the use of the Express framework or the size of the data being returned. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with Express and Google Cloud Functions when returning small amounts of data? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar issue where my cloud function was crashing due to the response being returned before the entire request had been received. To fix this problem, I decided to buffer the entire request body using a built-in function in my programming language.

By buffering the entire request body, I was able to ensure that the entire request had been received before processing it. This prevented any issues with the response being returned too early and helped to ensure that my cloud function was more reliable overall.

Here is the code snippet that I used to buffer the request body:

```
    // Read the request body into a buffer
const buffer = [];
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
  buffer.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  // Process the request body here
});
// Send response
```

In this code, I used the on('data') method to read the request body into a buffer, and the on('end') method to concatenate the buffer into a single string that could be processed by my code.

By using this approach, I was able to fix the issue with my cloud function crashing due to the response being returned too early. I hope this helps others who may be experiencing similar issues!